# Change icon color on scroll for vertical navigation in react

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app with vertical navigation
I am trying to add the feature where the colour of the icon changed on the scroll
the scroll looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhnHO.png)

Is there any method that lets you keep track of what section you currently are on in react?

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for a scroll event in a page. When a section crosses, for example, the middle of the viewport, then change color of an appropriate icon. You can also use IntersectionObserver

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   //watch for the window.scrollY changes and compare with the 
  //section offset, when they intersects, change the colour of the 
  //icon
 })
```